# Unable to read VSTS Online release variables

Tags: powershell, azure, environment-variables, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I'm working with VSTS environment variables and stuck with variables of a secret type.
I'm using POSH script (file) to generate a variable (in fact, to obtain the value from Azure Key Vault and the set this value to the variable):

***# Add as a script parameter during the release step***

```
-ResourceGroupNameArg "$(ResourceGroupName)" -KeyVaultNameArg "$(KeyVaultName)" -KeyVaultSecretNameArg "$(KeyVaultSecretName)"
```

***# The script itself***

```
Param(
   [string]$ResourceGroupNameArg,
   [string]$KeyVaultNameArg,
   [string]$KeyVaultSecretNameArg
)
<...>
$secret = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $KeyVaultNameArg -Name $KeyVaultSecretNameArg 
$secretValue = $secret.SecretValueText
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SQLAdministratorPassword;issecret=true]$secretValue"
```

***Here I can pass to the script different KeyVault names (according to my needs) - by substituting the $KeyVaultNameArg and $KeyVaultSecretNameArg variables.***

For any other variables configured using `##vso[task.setvariable variable=` I am able to retrieve them using the construction  `$env:DatabaseName` (for example in another POSH script) or `$(DatabaseName)` in agent phase step (using Hosted 2017 agent).

However, for the `issecret=true` variable or even for a manually created variable I'm unable to retrieve its values during the release deployment process.

[image: variables]
[image: script]
[image: release-error]
[image: step-release]

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=powershell#custom-variables) article,

> The values of hidden (secret) variables are stored securely on the
>   server and cannot be viewed by users after they are saved. During a
>   deployment, the Release Management service decrypts these values when
>   referenced by the tasks and passes them to the agent over a secure
>   HTTPS channel.

So IMO the variables should be accessible for the script (or even agent phase step) despite they are secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to these steps to do it:

1. Click Library tab
2. Click + Variable group
3. Specify variable group name
4. Enable Link secrets for an Azure Key vault as variables and link Azure key vault
5. Click +Add to add necessary secret(s)
6. Edit release definition
7. Choose Variables tab
8. Select Variable groups
9. Click Link variable group to link that variable group
10. Using the related variable directly in release task (`$(variable name)`)

Comment: Thanks for this guide, however, could you please clarify the situation with PowerShell and linking variables? Despite the VSTS inner library is an acceptable approach I'd like to have more control over it (here using the POSH scripts for accessing Azure KeyVault, gaining secrets and setting variables).

Comment: Based on the log, it does the same process, what's the result if you try it with my way?

Comment: I've already tried to configure my release using the library and variable groups. It worked, fact. But the main idea (and my main question) is to avoid binding by KeyVault name (which takes place using the library approach). I've updated my initial question for better understanding.

Comment: Try to print $secretValue (Write-Host $secretValue) and check whether the value is correct. BTW, both of these ways works fine for me.

Comment: Pls see details [here](https://imgur.com/a/pcpfsGv) and [here](https://imgur.com/a/WAMGNp2) - unfortunately setting variables by the script isn't working. Maybe you have suggestions why?

Comment: @Sergey Output it in the same script: `$secretValue = $secret.SecretValueText  Write-Host $secretValue`

Comment: Here is how it looks: `$secret = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $KeyVaultNameArg -Name $KeyVaultSecretNameArg;
$secretValue = $secret.SecretValueText;
Write-Host "secret from keyvault $secretValue"` and the output is `2018-05-18T08:25:02.7844159Z ##[command]& 'D:\a\r1\a\_XXXXXX_DACPAC\PS\vsts_release_script.ps1' -ResourceGroupNameArg "XXXXX" -KeyVaultNameArg "XXXX" -KeyVaultSecretNameArg "sqlAdminPassword";
2018-05-18T08:25:05.6311289Z secret from keyvault ***`.

Comment: It isn't output the actual value, just ***?

Comment: Yes, seems it is masked by asterisks - or I do not understand the logic of the script engine

Comment: What's the result if you run that script on your machine manually?

Comment: You can try to add a new secret to the key vault and use this secret and check the result.

Comment: Yes, probably the previous one was bugged idk why but now it looks like `2018-05-18T09:55:36.3864589Z secret2 from keyvault RandomValue`. Again, thanks for the assistance.